# Core Data: GROUP BY SUM of two properties

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

Do you know if it is possible to **GROUP** a fetchRequest **BY** the **SUM** of 2 properties?

I already tried:

```
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"senderUserId + receiverUserId"]];
```

Also:

```
NSExpression *sumExpr = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"add:to:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"senderUserId"], [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"receiverUserId"], nil]];
NSExpressionDescription *sum = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[sum setName:@"sum"];
[sum setExpression:sumExpr];
[sum setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[sum]];
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tried those things?

Comment: And also, what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe you really want to group by both of those user IDs instead of grouping by their sum?

Comment: Hi @TomHarrington, I got an error in the execution of the request: memory error - no messages.
I would like to group by [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"senderUserId", "receiverUserId"]]; but this is different than [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"receiverUserId", "senderUserId"]]; and then I get 2 results for each GROUP BY. For example: (123, 234) would be different than (234, 123). If I use SUM they are equal.

Comment: I know that Core Data is not the same as SQLite but just to say: GROUP BY SUM of two fields in SQLite is totally possible. That's why I thought that maybe it is possible in Core Data as well.

Comment: I get it, but is there any chance of two different entries having the same sum? For example, one user has senderUserId=123, receiverUserId=234 and another has has senderUserId=124, receiverUserId=233? "Sum" seems likely to generate bad results in some cases.

Comment: Hi @TomHarrington, in my code, there is NOT. Because one of the userIds is always mine.
I think I have to change my database Model. Thanks!